# Klein Gordon equation of fields via the definition of the time ordered product

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

My question is as follows:

Consider that,
$$ (-\partial_1^2+m^2)\langle 0|T(\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2))|0\rangle
$$
Due to the definition of the time ordered product one can get:

$$ (-\partial_1^2+m^2)\bigg\{\theta(t_1-t_2)\langle 0|\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)|0\rangle+\theta(t_2-t_1)\langle 0|\phi(x_2)\phi(x_1)|0\rangle\bigg\}
$$

Then what do we get? I mean what happened when the 2nd order partial derivative acts on the following term?

Comment: Why don't you just compute it? You are asking us to do the algebra for you?